# Is there a way to spawn mobs other than spiders?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have a slime farm with an iron golem inside that attracts the slime, but I noticed that it also works with some other mobs if it isn't lit up properly. So I turned afk for a while with light level -7 in the slime farm and a lot of mobs spawned! But when I went down I saw a spider that killed the iron golem. So is there a way to spawn all mobs other than spiders?

Comment: Are you using the Slime Chunk method? Or simply farming them in a swamp?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have the wrong strategy here.

Many (possibly all?) hostile mobs will attack Iron Golems. The spider may have been the mob to kill it, but all the mobs before the spider likely did damage to the golem, weakening it just enough to finally be killed by the spider.

So, the real problem is not preventing spider spawns, but preventing the golem from dying. Unfortunately, it is not possible to permanently keep it alive. That being said, there are some tricks to keep the golem alive for as long as possible.

- Frequently throw splash potions of instant health at the golem. Splash potions of instant health heal golems, but hurt hostile mobs.
- Make an [iron golem farm](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Iron_golem_farming), and a water pathway that leads the iron golems to the mobs. This is much more difficult, but a more permanent solution.

Comment: There is cactus so the mobs will run into it and damage them self, the problem is that the spider can job high enough so it damage the golem...

Comment: @Gustav Since that is a crucial difference, I suggest describing it in the original post. A picture would also be helpful.

Comment: I believe the Health Potions only harm Undead mobs (Skeletons and Zombies) - but they will heal Creepers, Spiders, Slimes and Witches. I can't remember where I read it though, so I might be wrong

Comment: Additionally, depending on the farming method (chunk vs swamp), light levels make all the difference - Slimes will spawn *at any light level* in a specified slime chunk.

Comment: "Frequently throw splash potions of instant health" - if that's a mob farm, use a dispenser with a clock to lob a splash potion of health at the golem every now and then. Feed the dispenser from a crate through a hopper and clock it with daylight sensor and you have this covered for a looong time. Also, normal spiders are 1 block high but 2 wide. Leaving the "window" to the golem small enough will only leave it exposed to skeleton arrows.

Comment: The best way is to keep the slime farm fully lit, so no other mobs than slimes spawn - and using a different method than a golem to lure other mobs in a dedicated, separate mob/XP farm. Primarily, the golem will be vulnerable to skeletons, not spiders.

Answer (score 0):

If you put fences around the Iron Golem it will stop mobs from getting to it while still attracting the mobs to it.